# ActiveRecord::Relation - query executed yet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Suppose I have the following models:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  scope :blue, where(color: 'blue')
end
```

If I have an instance of `Foo`, there are several ways to retrieve all of the blue `Bar` models associated with it. My question relates to determining whether or not the `bars` relation of a given `foo` has already been loaded.

This will execute a database query regardless of whether or not the full collection of bars is already loaded into memory:

`foo.bars.blue.all`

This won't execute a query if the `bars` were included by the query that loaded the `foo`. If they weren't loaded it will load all of the `bars` and then enumerate.

`foo.bars.select { |b| b.color == 'blue' }`

How can I determine whether or not a relation has been loaded without causing it to execute a query?

`foo.bars.some_method_to_determine_whether_or_not_they_are_in_memory_thanks`

Any ideas?

EDIT:

just to clarify, this is the sort of outcome I wish to achieve:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars

  def blue_bars
    if bars_already_loaded?
      # enumerate
    else
      # use the scope
    end
  end

  def red_bars
    ...
  end

  ...
end
```

Comment: Seems there is a `loaded?` method that does exactly what I'm looking for: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb

Comment: Ya, loaded is set when exec_queries is finished. Just a word of caution, It's not a good idea to browse rails master branch, especially now since master is Rails 4.0 dev. AR::Relation hasnt been changed much, but other classes have been drastically overhauled, moved or culled from the repo. I always pick the tag my project is on.